# Error running json-server from React Native app folder

Tags: json-server

I'm in the folder of an app created with `create-react-native-app`. I installed `json-server` with `sudo npm i -g json-server`. I've got a `db.json` in my app folder. When I try to run the server I get this error:

```sh
// ♥ json-server db.json

  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading db.json
  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:3000/photos

  Home
  http://localhost:3000

  Type s + enter at any time to create a snapshot of the database
Some error occurred { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:58:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'localhost' }
```

This occurs whether I'm running the expo server or not. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The localhost might be hidden in host entry location.

Kindly check it and remove.

Eg:

Go to terminal 
`cd /etc/hosts`

`#127.0.0.1`

remove the hash from localhost and run the json-server.